# Model Accuracy Using Transformer

Tags: sentiment-analysis, bert-language-model, floating-accuracy, transformer-model, imdb

I'm trying to increase the Accuracy of my Model. The model aims to leverage BERT's contextual understanding of language to perform binary classification on IMDb movie reviews. By fine-tuning specific layers of the pre-trained BERT model and integrating it into a neural network, the goal is to achieve high accuracy in classifying sentiment polarity (positive/negative) of movie reviews from the IMDb dataset.

Below is the code:

```
# Load the dataset but only keep the top n words, zero the rest
top_words = 5000
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = imdb.load_data(num_words=top_words)

# Truncate and pad input sequences
max_review_length = 500
X_train = sequence.pad_sequences(X_train, maxlen=max_review_length)
X_test = sequence.pad_sequences(X_test, maxlen=max_review_length)


# Convert integer sequences back to text
X_train_texts = [' '.join(map(str, x)) for x in X_train]
X_test_texts = [' '.join(map(str, x)) for x in X_test]

# Tokenize the input sequences
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')

# Truncate sequences to fit within BERT's maximum sequence length
max_sequence_length = 512
X_train = [tokenizer.encode(text, add_special_tokens=True, max_length=max_sequence_length, truncation=True) for text in X_train_texts]
X_test = [tokenizer.encode(text, add_special_tokens=True, max_length=max_sequence_length, truncation=True) for text in X_test_texts]

# Pad the tokenized sequences
X_train = sequence.pad_sequences(X_train, maxlen=max_sequence_length, padding='post', truncating='post')
X_test = sequence.pad_sequences(X_test, maxlen=max_sequence_length, padding='post', truncating='post')

# Load pre-trained BERT model
bert_model = TFBertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')

# Define input layer
input_layer = Input(shape=(max_sequence_length,), dtype='int32')

# BERT layer
bert_output = bert_model(input_layer)[0]

# Flatten layer
flatten_layer = Flatten()(bert_output)

# Output layer
output_layer = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(flatten_layer)

# Create model
model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)

# Make BERT layers trainable
for layer in bert_model.layers:
    if layer.name.startswith('pooler'):
        layer.trainable = True
    else:
        layer.trainable = False

# Compile the model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())


# Train the model
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=3, batch_size=64)

# Evaluate the model
scores = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=32)
print("BERT-based Model Accuracy: %.2f%%" % (scores[1] * 100))
```

Using the above code. I am getting this accuracy with **3 Epochs**

**[Accuracy Screenshot with 3 Epochs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wt4VU.png)**

When I tried using **10 Epochs**, I didn't see any great difference and it took almost 6 to 8 hours on **Kaggle Notebook** using **GPU T4x2**. It did stop due to inactivity insufficient memory of might be due to inactivity. I'm attaching the image as well so you guys can get an idea.

**[Screenshot failed attempt using 10 Epochs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CU3qU.png).**

Kindly, share some suggestions and solution to improve the accuracy of this model.